# Supremum & infimum logical proof

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove the following: Given two sets, $A, B \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and $A \subseteq B$, show that $$\sup A \le \sup B \land \inf A \ge \inf B$$

Here's what I did:

let $x = \sup A$ and $y = \sup B$. Then, for $A$: $$(1) \;(\forall a \in A) a\le x$$ $$ (2)\; (\forall a \in A)(a \le c \in \Bbb {R})x \le c $$
Now, from $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow$ $$(\exists b' \in B)(\forall a \in A)\;a \le b' $$
then, $b'$ is an upper bound for $A$, or: $$b' \in \{ m \in \Bbb{R} \mid m \ge a\} = M$$ and $x=\min M$
$$ \Rightarrow x \le b' \le y \Rightarrow \sup A \le \sup B $$

I need to verify that I'm doing it right. I've never done proofs before, but I'm loving it and working hard, so any advice would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

$A\subseteq B$ doesn’t imply what you say it implies in the 3rd row. Imagine a case where $A=B$ - in that case $b’\in A$ and so $A$ would have a maximum (which, we know, need not be true).

However, look at it from this perspective: if $y=\sup B$, $y$ is an upper bound of $B$, so it is an upper bound of $A$. ($y\ge b$ for all $b\in B$ so $y\ge b$ for all $b\in A$.) Thus, as one of the c’s in your clause (2) you can take $y$, and the conclusion $x\le y$ directly follows.

Comment: Thanks, it looks elegant :)